# Cartesian Product Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \times B$ = {$(x,y)$|$x \in A$ & $y \in B$}.

For every set A, $A \times \emptyset$ = $\emptyset \times A$ = $\emptyset$.

If $(x,y) \in A \times \emptyset$, then $x \in A$ & $y \in \emptyset$.  Why is this statement not possible?

Comment: Do you mean $A \times B$?

Comment: Yes thats what mean.

Comment: Not possible because $y\in\varnothing$ cannot be true. The empty set has no elements.

Answer (score 0):

The statement $(x,y)\in A\times\varnothing\implies x\in A\wedge y\in\varnothing$ is true.

The statement $x\in A\wedge y\in\varnothing$ is not true. This because the empty set has no elements.

So the statement $(x,y)\in A\times\varnothing$ is not true, leading to the conlusion that $A\times\varnothing$ has no elements, i.e. $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

The Cartesian product is a set of **couples** of elements. In the case $A\times \emptyset$ simply you have no elements to
put in the second place of the couple.